# show specific lines from all files with .txt extension

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I print specific lines (say the 7th and 15th) of each file in the current directory whose name ends in `.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *many* ways. Here are a few:

- `awk`

  ```
  awk 'FNR==7 || FNR==15' *.txt
  ```

  `FNR` is the line number of the current file. Because the default action in `awk` when an expression evaluates to true is to print the current line, this will print lines 7 and 15 of each `.txt` file.

Awk is the only tool I know that can easily (others can do it but not quite so simply) distinguish between the line number of all input and the line number of the current file. Therefore, the other suggestions involve shell loops:

- `sed`

  ```
  for f in *.txt; do sed -n '7p;15p' "$f"; done
  ```
- Perl

  ```
  for f in *.txt; do perl -ne 'print if $.==7 or $.==15' "$f"; done
  ```

  Or, to avoid the shell loop:

  ```
  perl -ne '$c++; print if $c==7 or $c==15; $c=0 if eof' *.txt
  ```

Comment: if i want to print specific lines (say the 7th to 15th) of each file in the current directory whose name ends in .txt? then how can i do @terdon

Comment: @Doe 7th *to* 15th or 7th *and* 15th?

Comment: my question was right but i want to know 7 to 15 also thats why i ask you no problem i solve it :) @terdon